solution verification | Solve the equality $\frac{2x-1}{x+2} =\frac{3x-1}{x+3}$
To solve the equality $\dfrac{2x-1}{x+2} = \dfrac{3x-1}{x+3}$,
I multiplied in form of $x$ and got that $\begin{align*}(2x-1)(x+3) = (3x-1)(x+2)&\implies  2x^2+6x-x-3 = 3x^2+6x -x-2\\&\implies x^2 = -1\end{align*}$
I know that if we take it with basic knowledge there is no solution, but my question is what is the answer in complex numbers. As much I know the answer would be $+i, -i$
Is it correct? Thanks!

Yes, those are the complex solutions. Just a comment on notation, it looks weird that you write $+i$ instead of just $i$. If the solutions were real, would you usually write something like "the solutions are $+2, +5$"?

The major difference of the question you just asked about inequality and here is that, $\mathbb{C}$ cannot equip any order. Strictly speaking, you cannot say $i>0,i=0$ or $i<0$. It is just like you compare a chocolate cake with your house, it is not comparable.

@AngaeMT while the complex numbers as a whole do not admit a total ordering, any subset of $\Bbb C$ homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$ does. If one chooses the subset $i\alpha$ where $\alpha\in\Bbb R$, it would be justified to say that $i$ is larger than $0$ as an element of that subset, and all solutions of the equation are indeed elements of that set. But at this point I'm splitting hairs into individual protein strands.

Yah but I mention that just wants OP to know the difference between two questions he posted.

Your answer is correct! You correctly cross-multiplied, FOILed, and simplified. If you are expected to find real solutions, this equation would have no real solutions but it would have the complex solutions $\pm i$.You found the answer to be $x^2=-1$, or $x=\sqrt{-1}$ which is the definition of $i$.
Note that you do not need to say "$+i$" just as you wouldn't say the solution to $2x-8=0$ is $+4$.

$\sqrt{-1}$ is not the definition of $i$.
